# How to add a Youtube alike hyperlink to a video that is not from Youtube

Tags: html, wordpress, video, youtube, mp4

I would like to know if there is a way I can put an hyperlink on a video that is from my own website, like Youtube does. The video is in mp4 format and I don't know wether there is a kind of embedded javascript code or something for doing that task. I thank you very much your attention.

I am currently managing my website through wordpress I would like to know if there is a way to do that by this way.

I can't just simply upload the video to Youtube and then embed the video in my website because the videos I am currently administrating are private.

Comment: Can you explain "Can put an hyperlink on a video that is from my own website, like Youtube does"

Comment: Im gonna guess that the OP wants to place layovers on the video similar in context that of youtube, where at various points through out the segment played there are links to whatever, where ever. My best answer to that, which really isn't an answer is its not as easy as just placing a layover a video, and javascript isn't what plays the video. It may load it dynamically into something that does but HTML 4/5 have different methods of embeding a video, and then theres always flash based players, and then theres a combination there of. The way I work sites with video is I usually use Flowplayer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you want to play your video directly on your website without having to upload it to a video service like youtube. For this you'd need to use the HTML5 video tag in your template(if you have access to your code). Or I'm guessing wordpress would have plugins for this that would just allow you to upload your video file and it would play it in your template for you.

[HTML5 video tag description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)